# Finding all nodes connected to a vertex in Prolog

Tags: optimization, prolog, dijkstra, path-finding, logic-programming

I am curious about pathfinding algorithms, so I took a look at Dijkstra's. I'm using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GazC3A4OQTE) video as a guide (and it's what I'm basing my graph on). Here is the graph I am working from:

[image]

I now want to be able to find all connections of a given vertex. I think that I should use `findall` for this, which I tried to use in the `all_connections` goal below. However, with `main`, my output is `[b,b,b,b]`. Why is that happening? That makes no sense. If you understand what I am doing wrong please let me know.

```
connection(s, c, 3).
connection(c, l, 2).
connection(l, i, 4).
connection(l, j, 4).
connection(i, j, 6).
connection(i, k, 4).
connection(j, k, 4).
connection(k, e, 5).
connection(e, g, 2).
connection(g, h, 2).
connection(h, f, 3).
connection(f, d, 5).
connection(d, a, 4).
connection(b, d, 4).
connection(b, a, 3).
connection(b, s, 2).
connection(b, h, 1).
connection(a, s, 7).

are_connected(A, B, Score) :-
    connection(A, B, Score);
    connection(B, A, Score).

all_connections(A, Z) :-
    findall(A, are_connected(A, _, _), Z).

main :-
    all_connections(b, X),
    write(X).
```

Comment: Note: I just solved my problem. Here was how I used `findall`: the first argument was the result from the goal that would be solved for each time, the second was the functor call, and the third was the result: `findall(Connected, are_connected(Node, Connected, _), Connections).`

Comment: It's been some time I haven't seen fanfold paper (the last time in the office for building security, with the NEC pinwriter that goes with it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Congratulations on solving your problem. If you post the solution as an answer, we can upvote it.

This is a comment on something else: Since you are a relative beginner, **now** is the best possible time to learn good coding conventions. Specifically, this:

```
are_connected(A, B, Score) :-
    connection(A, B, Score);
    connection(B, A, Score).
```

is **very bad**. Prolog's disjunction is a very powerful, and often confusing, tool. When you use it, the use should **really stick out**. Otherwise it's easy to mistake your code for this:

```
are_connected(A, B, Score) :-
    connection(A, B, Score),
    connection(B, A, Score).
```

The way you have written this, the semicolon is very easy to miss at the end of a line. Rule of thumb: **You should never use `;` at the end of a line.**

Alternatives:

```
are_connected(A, B, Score) :-
    connection(A, B, Score).
are_connected(A, B, Score) :-
    connection(B, A, Score).
```

(This transformation only works since the entire body of your definition is a disjunction.)

```
are_connected(A, B, Score) :-
    (   connection(A, B, Score)
    ;   connection(B, A, Score) ).
```

Or:

```
are_connected(A, B, Score) :-
    (
        connection(A, B, Score)
    ;
        connection(B, A, Score)
    ).
```

You get the idea. Each of these variants make it clear that what you are doing is **very different** from using conjunction.

Comment: As seen in [Coding Guidelines for Prolog](https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.2899) on page 10 of the PDF.

Comment: I still have the fervent wish that "Coding Guidelines for Prolog" were in a HTML page somewhere with commenting possibility instead of mummified inside a PDF on arxiv.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer There's https://www.arxiv-vanity.com/ for rendering arXiv papers as HTML, though it chokes on this one. And offers no commenting anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I solved my problem:

```
are_connected(A, B, S) :-
    connection(A, B, S)
    ;
    connection(B, A, S).
```

Many thanks to Isabelle for giving me advice on proper conventions.